# Stop Groovy console truncating output?

Tags: groovy-console

Is it possible to stop the Groovy console truncating output?

Using the 1.8.4 console, if I execute the following script:

```
for (i in 0..4000) println i
```

I get the following output:

```
01
602
603
...
3999
4000
```

I can't see any options to preserve all program output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file:

https://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/ui/Console.groovy

contains this code:

```
// Maximum number of characters to show on console at any time
int maxOutputChars = System.getProperty('groovy.console.output.limit','20000') as int
```

Which seems to be the thing I want to change. There was even a JIRA on this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4425

But so far I haven't been able to pass this property as a `-D` option through `groovyConsole` or `groovyConsole.bat`, the started console immediately closes. Will update if/when I figure out how to easily pass this property through to the console..

Comment: Was typing in something here my mistake - sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon the accepted answer, groovyconsole uses JAVA_OPTS, so anything you set in there will be picked up.  For instance, if you wanted to increase the max memory to 4 GB and the console limit to 200,000, then you could do this statement prior to running groovyConsole:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m -Dgroovy.console.output.limit=200000"
```